# Implement mask for anchor-negative in list of triplets

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a generator in producing my TensorFlow data, as triplets (`anchor`, `positive`, `negative`), in batches. Each batch is a list of such triplets, making up the list `labels`. Using code from [Moindrot's blog on triplet loss](https://omoindrot.github.io/triplet-loss) we get a mask for positives and negatives: With

```py
labels_equal = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(labels, 0), tf.expand_dims(labels, 1))
mask = tf.logical_not(labels_equal)
```

we get a mask of negatives (non-equal labels). If I have `labels=[1,1,2,3,3,4]` the mask will be:

```
[[ F F T T T T ],
 [ F F T T T T ],
 [ T T F T T T ],
 [ T T T F F T ],
 [ T T T F F T ],
 [ T T T T T F ]]
```

The labels are set up such that in groups of 3 they form anchor, positive and negative (triplet).

I'm trying to implement a negative mask for balanced triplets. I.e. a mask where only the negative to its anchor is `True` for each line. How do I find this negative mask such that only the anchor-negative entries percolate through?

**Expected output** for `labels=[1,1,2,3,3,4]`:

```
[[ F F T F F F ],
 [ F F F F F F ],
 [ T F F F F F ],
 [ F F F F F T ],
 [ F F F F F F ],
 [ F F F T F F ]]
```

---

Notes:

- I have tried to use [tfa's triplet loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/TripletSemiHardLoss), but it's not balanced (bad for testing accuracy, recall, etc.).
- Labels have been relabeled, such that the labels of each triplet is batch-unique and won't match other triplets in the batch.

Comment: The labels represent the id of the vectors I'm using. But I've relabeled the vectors to be unique per-batch. I will then use the positive and negative mask to calculate triplet loss for each triplet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* only want anchor-negative `True` in the negative mask, you can accomplish this with a mix of `tf.tile`, `tf.linalg.band_part` and `tf.transpose`:

```py
labels_equal = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(labels, 0), tf.expand_dims(labels, 1))
mask = tf.logical_not(labels_equal)
triplet_mask = tf.tile(
    [
        [False, False, True],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
    ],
    multiples=[d // 3 for d in mask.shape],
)
triplet_mask = tf.linalg.band_part(triplet_mask, 0, 2)
triplet_mask = triplet_mask | tf.transpose(triplet_mask)
```

I would suggest, however, you rather change the model to accept a list of triplets. It simplifies both training and testing.